# How to scroll a div element containing all images in a Facebook album to load all images using Python & Selenium

Tags: python, facebook, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scroll

[Album Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyFCJ.jpg)

I am using Selenium to scrape images from a Facebook album, but not all images are loaded by default. Instead, the images are loaded as I scroll down the page. The images are contained within a div as highlighted in picture.

How can I use Selenium to programmatically scroll this div element to ensure that all images are loaded?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

I want to scroll down to the botom of the scrollable div to load all images

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: scraping is not allowed anyway, you must use the graph api instead